# finding the pointer to an element in linked list in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

i want to get the pointer to an element in linked list in c. 
here is my code. Im getting the error "incompatible types when returning type ‘bigList’ but ‘struct bigList **’ was expected". please help. thanks

```
     /*this is the struct*/
     struct bigList
     {
      char data;
      int count;
      struct bigList *next;
      };


      int main(void)
      {
        struct bigList *pointer = NULL;

        *getPointer(&pointer, 'A');  //here how do I store the result to a pointer 

       }

    /*function to return the pointer*/    
    bigList *getPointer(bigList *head, char value)
    {
      bigList temp;
      temp=*head;

      while(temp!=NULL)
       {
        if(temp->data==value)
        break;

        temp = temp->next;     
        }
    return *temp;      //here I get the error I mentioned
     }
```

Comment: At least the syntax, please...! If you didn't even bother to read carefully the section on pointer syntax in that C tutorial, then you certainly don't have the slightest idea about what is going on, and that's dangerous.

Comment: im sorry. im new to c , I forgot to add the typedef declaration i used. and I think I screwed it up...got lot to study..pointers are confusing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 pointers, a head pointer to your base list and the place you want to return your pointer:

```
  int main(void)
  {
    struct bigList *pointer = NULL;

    struct bigList *retValPtr = getPointer(pointer, 'A');  //here how do I store the result to a pointer 

   }

   struct bigList *getPointer(struct bigList *head, char value)
   {
       struct bigList *temp;  // Don't really need this var as you could use "head" directly.
       temp = head;

       while(temp!=NULL)
       {
           if(temp->data==value)
             break;

           temp = temp->next;     
       }

       return temp;  // return the pointer to the correct element
   }
```

Notice how I've changed around the pointers such that they are all the same type whereas your code is kinda random about thsi.  It matters quite a bit!

Comment: thank you, i forgot to mention the typedef decleration i used, looks like i screwed it up....